# Example of the joint distribution which expectation does not exist

Tags: probability

I need some example of two distributions $x$ and $y$, $E[x]$ and $E[y]$ are exist but $E[xy]$ not.

Comment: Why do you want them?
FWIW, The ratio of 2 standard Normal RVs is Cauchy.

Comment: @Inquest: How is your latter remark pertinent to the question at hand?

Answer (score 1):

Let the random variable $x$ satisfy ${\Bbb P}[x=n]=4/(n(n+1)(n+2))$ for all $n\ge 1$ and let $y=x$ (that is, $y$ always has the same value as $x$.)  Then ${\Bbb E}[x]={\Bbb E}[y]=2$ but ${\Bbb E}[xy]={\Bbb E}[x^2]=\infty$.

Comment: The same remark made to Andre also applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Let random variable $X$ have density function $\frac{2}{x^3}$ when $x\ge 1$, and $0$ elsewhere. Then 
$$E(X)=\int_1^\infty \frac{2x\,dx}{x^3}.$$
Integrate. The mean is $2$.

Let $Y=X$. Then 
$$E(XY)=\int_1^\infty \frac{2x^2\,dx}{x^3}.$$
This integral diverges.

Comment: The integral diverges, but still *exists* as a Lebesgue integral (after all, the integrand is nonnegative and measurable). Perhaps that's splitting the hairs too finely, but a symmetrization of this will yield an unequivocal example.